# Avoid focus on link in html-table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a bunch of tabular data in a table like shown on the pictures below.

I'd like to avoid hitting the link(a href) when tabbing through data to set it.

Not using Jquery, I'm using prototype 1.6.

Is there any way to do this, since I don't know the I'd of the row below? (I have done it on from the checkBox to the input text, but I know both their IDs at the same time.. Now I don't?

What I did on checkbox was:

```
function checkboxOnFocus(id){
    var adjustField = document.getElementById('a'+id);
    adjustField.focus();
    adjustField.select();
}
```

Picture of "text"-field highlighted:
[image: Picture of link highlighted(This is what I wish to avoid):]

Picture of link highlighted(This is what I wish to avoid):
[image: picture of link highlighted]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your HTML set the `tabindex` attribute of the links to -1.  This excludes them from the tabbing order, no Javascript necessary.

Comment: Just what I was looking for :-)

Comment: @Anders: AFAIK, Internet Explorer has supported having a negative tabindex longer than any other browser.  Which version did you test it in?

Comment: Now it works, sorry I didn't say so earlier, don't know what I did wrong though :(

Comment: @AndersMetnik: No worries, I didn't lose any sleep over it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

- first of all do not alter check box into input textbox.
- to avoid dotted square of text link after click, add **`outline:none;`** in css
- add class to avoid hitting the link(a href) when tabbing through data to set it. `.check{ cursor:text;}`

Comment: Cursor:text; does nothing put making the cursor change to the text indicator, as far as I can see.. It's not the cursor functionality I wan't to change it's the pressing on the keyboards "tab"-key which changes focus from 1 object to another..